# How can I print the lines from the text file next to random generated numbers

Tags: python, random, filereader

The text file is "ics2o.txt" and I don't know how to print numbers next to the lines

```html
import random 
print ("----------------------------------------------------------")
print ("Student Name Student Mark")
print ("----------------------------------------------------------")

f = open("ics2o.txt")
for line in f:
  x = len(f.readlines())
  for i in range (x):
    contents = f.read()
    print(str(contents) + str(random.randint(75,100)))
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly, doing `print("----...")` is a bad practice, at least use string multiplication:`print("-"*10)`
2. Secondly, always open files using 'with' keyword. (u can google it up why)
3. Thirdly, the code:

   ```
   with open("ics2o.txt") as f:
       for i,j in enumerate(f):
           print(i,j)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
for line in f:
  x = len(f.readlines())
  for i in range (x):
    contents = f.read()
    print(str(contents) + str(random.randint(75,100)))
```

The problem is that you are reading the file in at least 3 different ways which causes none of them to work the way you want. In particular, `f.readlines()` consumes the entire file buffer, so when you next do `f.read()` there is nothing left to read. Don't mix and match these. Instead, you should use `line` since you are iterating over the file already:

```
for line in f:
    print(line + str(random.randint(75,100)))
```

The lesson here is don't make things any more complicated than they need to be.